# Batch: trimming an output of a sql file processed in batch

Tags: sql, batch-file, db2, db2-luw

**Batch:**

```
db2 -stwl%LOG% -f %SQL_DIR%\test.sql > %DATA_ROOT%\%NAME%.txt
```

**SQL:**
pretty long so i won't post it here, its a huge select query that gives this output:

```
1                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

A testline for example  <--these are the only lines i want to output            
and another one      <-- these are the only lines i want to output                                                           



  2 Satz/Sätze ausgewählt.
```

Is there a way to minimize the output into the txt file to just the 2 lines i marked above? (without using some extra perl/other external code)

maybe something like another character in the db2 call to just print the 2 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at `db2batch` and its output options.

- Performance option should be 0 (zero)
- Query option should be on

Take a look at the [db2batch manual](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002043.html) for details.